# Calculate words value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox on a form where the user types some text. Each letter is assigned a different value like a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 and so forth. For example, if the user types "aa bb ccc" the output on a label should be like:

```
aa = 2
bb = 4
dd = 6
Total value is (12)
```

I was able to get the total value by looping through the textbox string, but how do I display the total for each word. This is what I have so far:

```
For letter_counter = 1 To word_length
    letter = Mid(txtBox1.Text, letter_counter, 1)

    If letter.ToUpper = "A" Then
        letter_value = 1
    End If
    If letter.ToUpper = "B" Then
        letter_value = 2
    End If
    If letter.ToUpper = "C" Then
        letter_value = 3
    End If
    If letter.ToUpper = "D" Then
        letter_value = 4
    End If
    If letter.ToUpper = "E" Then
        letter_value = 5
    End If
    If letter.ToUpper = " " Then    
        letter_value = 0
    End If

    totalletter = totalletter + letter_value

    Label1.Text = Label1.Text & letter_value & " "
    txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text & letter_value & " "
Next letter_counter
```

Comment: What is `txtBox2.Text` for?  Also, where is `word_length` defined?

Comment: I think you'll need two loops - the outer loop for each word, and the inner loop to determine the value each word.  Is " " your delimiter for a word?

Comment: you can use swith statement Switch(your text){case "A" : later_value=2; totalletter =totalletter + letter_value; break; } this logic may help you

Comment: txtbox2.Text is for displaying the result. My delimiter is " " for a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple little routine should do the trick:

```
Private Sub CountLetters(Input As String)
    Label1.Text = ""
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Dim dicLetters As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
    dicLetters.Add("a"c, 1)
    dicLetters.Add("b"c, 5)
    dicLetters.Add("c"c, 7)
    For Each word As String In Input.Split
        Dim wordtotal As Integer = 0
        For Each c As Char In word
            wordtotal += dicLetters(Char.ToLower(c))
        Next
        total += wordtotal
        'Display word totals here
        Label1.Text += word.PadRight(12) + "=" + wordtotal.ToString.PadLeft(5) + vbNewLine
    Next
    'Display total here
    Label1.Text += "Total".PadRight(12) + "=" + total.ToString.PadLeft(5)
End Sub
```

Comment: That works fine if the values is incremented by one, but it is not. For example, a = 1, b = 2. c = 3, d = 4, e = 50, f = 60. How do I specify the value for each letter? Thanks!

Comment: Would have been nice to know in the first place.  Are the values random? Or applied by an algorithm?

Comment: The values are not random, but they do get change. So I am looking for a way to specify each letter's value individually in the code. Like:

Comment: The values are not random, but they do get change. So I am looking for a way to specify each letter's value individually in the code. Like: a =1, b=2, j=3, d=4, h=5, e=50, f=60, etc... Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: A dictionary(Of Char, Integer) is probably the way to go.  The character is the key and the value is the value.

Comment: For Each word As String In Input.Split
            Dim dicLetters As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
            dicLetters.Add("a", 1)
            dicLetters.Add("b", 5)
            dicLetters.Add("c", 7)
            Dim wordtotal As Integer = 0
            For Each c As Char In txtBox1.Text
                wordtotal += dicLetters(c)
            Next
            total += wordtotal

Comment: I tried the above as you suggested, but it only calculates one word. If I enter for example aa ccc, I get {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."} and the program breaks.

Comment: The first thing I want to mention is in the project properties, in the compile tab, set every option except compare to `on`.  This will allow Intellisense to highlight the kind of problem you're having, and will also show you other areas where you may have been sloppy with your code.  You weren't adding the keys as characters your were adding them as strings into the dictionary.  To do a character literal in VB.Net use the `c` suffix.  For instance "a" is a string, but "a"c is a char.  With that change your code works.

Comment: Simply add the `c` to the string literals in your Add statements, `dicLetters.Add("a"c, 1)`

Comment: I tried that and now it calculates one word only. If I type aa bb for example, I get "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: Did you add the `c` to all the Add statements?  As per the example I left in my last comment.

Comment: Yes I did for three letters to test it out, and as I said it only calculates one word.

Comment: I updated my answer to show working code using a dictionary.  The only other modification I made was to use the ToLower method in case you get words with capitals.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you an idea:

```
Dim listOfWordValues As New List(Of Integer)
For letter_counter = 1 To word_length
    letter = Mid(txtBox1.Text, letter_counter, 1)

    If letter = " " Then 
        totalletter= totalletter + letter_value   
        listOfWordValues.Add(letter_value)
        letter_value  = 0
     Else
        letter_value += Asc(letter.ToUpper) - 64
     End If
Next letter_counter

totalletter = totalletter + letter_value
If Not txtBox1.Text.EndsWith(" ") Then listOfWordValues.Add(letter_value)
txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text & string.Join(", ", listOFWordValues);
```

Comment: I tried the code above, and if I entered aa cc ddd, get 1, 3, 4 where it should be 2, 4, 12 where the value of each letter is a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.   Assuming txtBox1 is the string the user enters and " " (space) is the word delimiter:

```
Dim words As String() = txtBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim totalValue As Integer = 0
Dim wordValue As Integer = 0

For Each word As String In words

    wordValue = 0

    For letter_counter = 1 To word.Length

        Dim letter As String = Mid(txtBox1.Text, letter_counter, 1)
        Select letter.ToUpper()
          Case "A":
              wordValue = wordValue + 1
          Case "B":
              wordValue = wordValue + 2
          ' And so on
        End Select
    Next

    totalValue = toalValue + wordValue
Next
```

The above code first takes the entered text from the user and splits it on " " (space).

Next it sets two variables - one for the total value and one for the individual word values, and initializes them to 0.

The outer loop goes through each word in the array from the Split performed on the user entered text.  At the start of this loop, it resets the wordValue counter to 0.

The inner loop goes through the current word, and totals up the values of the letter via a `Select` statement.

Once the inner loop exits, the total value for that word is added to the running totalValue, and the next word is evaluated.

At the end of these two loops you will have calculated the values for each word as well as the total for all the worlds.

The only thing not included in my sample is updating your label(s).

Comment: I have tried to input aa bb and the result was "4" in the textbox where it should be: aa = 2, bb = 4. It looks like the code is counting instead of calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim c As String = "ABCDE"
    Dim s0 As String
    Dim totalletter As Integer

    For x As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        s0 = s.Substring(x, 1).ToUpper
        If c.Contains(s0) Then
            totalletter += c.IndexOf(s0) + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(totalletter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem using a dictionary that maps each letter to a number.

```
Private Shared ReadOnly LetterValues As Dictionary(Of Char, Integer) = GetValues()

Private Shared Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of Char, Integer))
    Dim values As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
    Dim value As Integer = 0
    For Each letter As Char In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        value += 1
        values.Add(letter, value)
    Next
    Return values
End Function

Public Function CalculateValue(input As String) As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each letter As Char In input.ToUpperInvariant()
        If LetterValues.ContainsKey(letter) Then
            sum += LetterValues.Item(letter)
        End If
    Next
    Return sum
End Function
```

Usage example:

```
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each segment As String In "aa bb ccc".Split()
        Dim value = CalculateValue(segment)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", segment, value)
        sum += value
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Total value is {0}", sum)

    ' Output
    ' aa = 2
    ' bb = 4
    ' ccc = 9
    ' Total value is 15
```